# Query Regarrding GCM services

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the GCM Services for my application , but unfortunately If there is is **no** GOOGLE PLAY STORE installed on the device then GCM is not supported.

However manually, Can PLAY STORE be downloaded, and then CAN GCM be used on that ?

Comment: Not sure if you're correct on the need of the Google Play Store, but if this really is an requirement you shouldn't worry to much about it in my opinion. Every Android phone which isn't rooted or doesn't have permission from Google has the Google Play Store. People that don't have it, shouldn't be surprised not to have proper support from apps.

Comment: He is correct, Google Play Store is needed, but I agree with Stefan, don't care about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can PLAY STORE be downloaded

Only in violation of Google's copyrights.

> and then CAN GCM be used on that ?

I would not assume that this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article stating Google Play Services can now be installed manually: 
http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/09/26/google-play-services-can-now-be-installed-manually-from-the-play-store/

The link they provide to download the Google Play Services manually is here: 
http://www.appbrain.com/app/google-play-services/com.google.android.gms

I hope this helps rolling.stones. Unless you have a specific device you are trying to develop your app for, then you may consider not worrying about those devices. 
If... the device has the previous version's Google Market, the device could update automatically once having internet access.